# Getting Column Values of Selected Rows/Row in jquery Datatable

Tags: jquery, dom, datatable

I'm stuck with following code. I wanted to get columns values of selected Rows/row in a datatable. i have use this code

code of DataTable :

```
var table = $('#tableId').DataTable({
        "ajax": {
            "url": "Content",
            "dataSrc": "",
            data: {sectionUrl: "", siteUrl: siteurl}
        },
        "columns": [
//            {"defaultContent": "<input type='checkbox' name='vehicle' id='checkID'>"},
            {"data": "postIMAGE", "render": function (data) {
                    return '<img src=' + data + ' width="154" height="115"/>';
                }},
            {"data": "postTITLE"},
            {"data": "postURL", "render": function (data) {
                    return '<a href=' + data + ' target="_blank"/>' + data + '</a>';
                }},
            {"data": "postSection"}

        ]
    });
```

.

```
$('#tableId tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
});

$('#button').click(function () {

    var selectedRows = table.rows('.selected').data();
    var results = "";

    for (i = 0; i < selectedRows.length; i++) {
        alert();
    }
});
```

i want get the values of columns

Comment: have you tried alert(selectedRows[i])  ?

Comment: yeh it's return an object. doent know how read that object. And I tried with ( selectedRows[i].length  ) it shows undefined in alert

Comment: can you post object which you are getting

Comment: alert shows [object Object]

Comment: see the answer posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access values from object as,

```
$('#button').click(function () {

   var selectedRows = table.rows('.selected').data();

 //if you are getting array of objects inside main object
   alert(selectedRows[0].postTITLE);
   alert(selectedRows[0].postURL);

  // if you are getting just plain object you can access it as
    alert(selectedRows.postTITLE);
    alert(selectedRows.postURL);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access selected rows in server side rendering by cols name from Datatable

```
$('#button').click(function (){
   let rows = $('#tableElement').rows( { selected: true } ).data().map(x=>x.cols_name).toArray();
         console.log(rows);
  });
```